# docx Property 'addSection' is private and only accessible within class 'File'

Tags: javascript, next.js, docx

const versionList = Object.keys(releaseNote)
for (const key of versionList) {
// Skip the version if none of its release notes are selected for cherry-picking.
const shouldInclude = cherryPick[key].some(Boolean)
if (!shouldInclude) {
continue
}

```
// Add version title
doc.addSection({
  properties: {},
  children: [
    new Paragraph({
      children: [
        new TextRun({
          text: key,
          bold: true,
          size: 16,
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
})

// Iterate over each release note in the current version.
for (let i = 0; i < releaseNote[key].length; i++) {
  // Check if that release note is selected or not
  if (cherryPick[key][i]) {
    // Add a bullet point before each release note.
    doc.addSection({
      properties: {},
      children: [
        new Paragraph({
          children: [
            new TextRun({
              text: '•',
              bold: true,
            }),
            new TextRun({
              text: releaseNote[key][i],
            }),
          ],
        }),
      ],
    })
  }
}
```

i am trying to add a section, but this is not working, any solutions

Answer (score -1):

I am also trying to find the solution. There is one case, but it is not very cool.

```js
 const doc = new Document({
  sections: [
  // Your sections
  ],
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35708253)